# Problem with the geometry of two balls inside a jar

Tags: geometry, physics

lets say we have 2 balls inside a jar with radius 1.5, I am trying to calculate the torque with respect to the point of contact of the left ball with the jar.

so far I have that the weight of the object is at a distance of 1.5R with the pivot(moving the weight in his line of action such that is perpendicular with the pivot point).

however I dont have the "straight line" distance of the normal force_f "point of contact of the right ball with the floor"
and the normal force_j "point of contact of ball with the jar

$$\Sigma \tau = -1.5RMG+"?"N_f +"?"N_j$$

"
[image]

Comment: do you have any questions?

Comment: The forces are not marked on the diagram. Centers are not marked for reference...

Comment: @Moti what centers?

Comment: The torque is calculated by using half the distance between the centers of the balls and the weight of the ball.

Comment: @I think is R...

Comment: book answer says that is around (1/sqrt(3))mg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the *free body diagram* is as follows:

[image]

the four reactions can be calculated by imposing the respective *equilibrium on the translation*:

$$
\begin{cases}
R_A - \frac{1}{2}R_B = 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R_B - P_1 = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}R_B - R_D = 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R_B + R_C - P_2 = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
R_A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1 \\
R_B = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1 \\
R_C = P_1 + P_2 \\
R_D = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1 \\
\end{cases}\,.
$$

If for verification we want to impose *equilibrium on the rotation* with respect to $B$:

$$
-R_A\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r + P_1\frac{1}{2}r + R_C\frac{1}{2}r - R_D\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r - P_2\frac{1}{2}r = 0
$$

i.e.

$$
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r + P_1\frac{1}{2}r + (P_1+P_2)\frac{1}{2}r - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r - P_2\frac{1}{2}r = 0
$$

which result in an identity $0=0$, the check is satisfied.

---

By imposing equilibrium on the translation and rotation of the system of the two balls:

$$
\begin{cases}
R_A - R_D = 0 \\
R_C - P_1 - P_2 = 0 \\
-R_A\sqrt{3}\,r - R_C\,r + P_1\,2\,r + P_2\,r = 0
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
R_A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1 \\
R_C = P_1 + P_2 \\
R_D = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}P_1 \\
\end{cases}\,.
$$

Naturally, if $R_B$ is needed, the body system must be exploded as above.

Comment: it is possible to aprroach this problems taking both balls as a single object with center of mass in B?